# Source code for CMS_ContentInfo_print_ctx function

Tags: openssl

I am trying to find the source code for an OpenSSL function `CMS_ContentInfo_print_ctx`. I have searched through the code and not found anything so I assume the code is auto generated.

Can anyone tell me where this code is generated or how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to find the source code for an OpenSSL function ... I have searched through the code and not found anything so I assume the code is auto generated.

Many times OpenSSL uses uses macros to take  base name, like `ASIdOrRange`, and expand it into a collection of functions. `grep` is your friend:

```
openssl-1.0.2h$ grep -IR sk_ * | grep '#' | grep define
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_new(type, cmp) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_new_null(type) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_free(type, st) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_num(type, st) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_value(type, st,i) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_set(type, st,i,val) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_zero(type, st) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_push(type, st, val) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_unshift(type, st, val) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_find(type, st, val) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_find_ex(type, st, val) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_delete(type, st, i) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_delete_ptr(type, st, ptr) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_insert(type, st,val, i) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_set_cmp_func(type, st, cmp) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_dup(type, st) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_pop_free(type, st, free_func) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_deep_copy(type, st, copy_func, free_func) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_shift(type, st) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_pop(type, st) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_sort(type, st) \
crypto/stack/safestack.h:# define SKM_sk_is_sorted(type, st) \
...
```

In this particular case:

```
openssl-1.0.2h$ grep -iIR CMS_ContentInfo * | grep void
apps/cms.c:static void receipt_request_print(BIO *out, CMS_ContentInfo *cms);
apps/cms.c:static void receipt_request_print(BIO *out, CMS_ContentInfo *cms)
crypto/cms/cms_lcl.h:CMS_ContentInfo *cms_Data_create(void);
crypto/cms/cms_lib.c:CMS_ContentInfo *cms_Data_create(void)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, macros are a bit of a headache 